# Solution to an optimization problem

Tags: optimization, computer-science

I see optimization problems of the following form a lot in the field I am researching. I want to know more about it and its solution. Would be great if someone could provide a not-too-long explanation.

$$\arg\min_x\quad\mathbf{x}^TW_k\mathbf{x} \quad \text{subject to} \quad y=D\mathbf{x}$$

Comment: Do you want to minimize or maximize $x^{T}W_{k}x$?  Are there multiple terms or just one $W_{k}$ matrix?

Comment: They usually go under the heading of quadratic optimisation (with linear constraints).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to type a term at the beginning! It's a minimization problem, edited. @BrianBorchers

Comment: That helped, thank you @mlc

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you want to minimize. This supports a simple Lagrangian approach to solution. The Lagrangian is
$$L(x,\lambda) = x^TW_kx - \lambda^T ( y - D x ) = 0$$
where $\lambda$ is the Lagrange multiplier. The optimality conditions are
$$W_k x + D^T \lambda = 0, \quad D x = y$$
which can be expressed in block form:
$$\begin{bmatrix} W_k & D^T \\ D & 0 \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ \lambda \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ y \end{bmatrix}$$
Any optimal point must satisfy these conditions, but this is not a guarantee that such a point *exists*; additional conditions must be satisfied. The most common requirement is that $W_k$ is positive semidefinite, which guarantees that the objective is nonnegative.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, how do you know the optimal conditions are the one stated in your answer?

Comment: I'd recommend reading material such as Convex Optimization by Boyd & Vandenberghe or Optimization by Vector Space Methods by David Luenberger.

Comment: I did actually skim through the book (convex optimization by Boyd) before asking this question but didn't find a formulation like this.

Comment: I suppose the book could be better organized, but it's there. The entire chapter on duality, the chapter on equality constrained algorithms...